# Unique Count by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

How would i do a unique count, so that the count for ID # 1: would be Green - 2, Red - 1, Blue - 1 and for ID#2, Orange - 2, Pink - 1, Blue - 1, White - 1.

Then I need to rank the colors using the RANK Function by ID. I've seen online how to use the rank function.

I am using sql server 2014.

Comment: You know how to use `rank()`, but you don't know `group by`?

Comment: i've seen how to use rank () online, but i need a unique count of each color by ID. I know how to use group by, i.e group by id

Comment: SELECT id, count(color) as color into #D1 From #Table1.

Comment: nvmd i got it figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you are looking for is:

```
select id, color, count(*) as cnt,
       rank() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as rnk
from t
group by id, color;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `id,color` and then rank based on the order of the count

```
select *, rank() over (order by cnt desc)
from
    (select *, count(*) as cnt
    from YourTable
    group by id, color)
```